# Is there a way to plot 3D vector functions (also known as vector-valued functions) in Wolfram|Alpha?

Tags: wolfram-alpha, graph

Is there a way to plot 3D vector functions (also known as [vector-valued functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector-valued_function)) in Wolfram|Alpha?

I know it's possible to plot regular vectors, by typing in `vector {2,5,3}` [for example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=vector+%7B2,5,3%7D), but I would like to be able to plot an equation like:

```
 r(t) = <2t, cos(t)^2, t>
```

I've looked at the Wolfram Alpha documentation and haven't been able to find a way to do this. However, WA sometimes uses different terminology than I'm used to, so it's possible there's a way and I just don't know how to articulate it to WA.

Has anybody had any success doing this, or have any suggestions for how to figure it out?

What I'm looking for is something like this:

[image: vector-val-func]

Comment: Not a webapp, but a free software that can do this: http://www.spacetime.us/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already have access to desktop software which can plot graphs like these. What I am looking for is something specifically web based.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, but use Mathematica notation:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{2t, Cos[t]^2, t}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[Example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ParametricPlot3D%5B%7B2t%2C+Cos%5Bt%5D%5E2%2C+t%7D%2C+%7Bt%2C+0%2C+10%7D%5D%0A):

[image: Parametric plot on wolfram alpha]

Comment: Fantastic, thank you!! I kept trying to figure this out, and couldn't. I will assign a bounty to this question and award it to you.

Comment: You can often get WolframAlpha to do something by giving it the appropriate Mathematica code.